# This community should include opinion and subjects which fall under creative English

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Creative English and public opinion is a part of English and of communication.
If you do not allow for such communication on this site, you will soon become irrelevant and ineffective as happens to every academic endeavor which ignores hypothetical and abstract creativity.

The English language is not a static object.  It is evolving.

It is crucial that you allow the following tag in this community `word-creation`

My question is the best example of the type of academic creativity which is necessary in this community.

[Help me create an adjective for "in heart"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/585890/help-me-create-an-adjective-for-in-heart)

Not only is this type of question necessary to be allowed for academic growth, the type of answer I received was of a very appropriate academic nature.  It was educational and thought provoking.

Many creative writers use this site to do things with the English language which go beyond the scope of high school English.  These are advanced topics which should be allowed or this site is not academic in nature at all.

Academia is not only about research and known study. Creative problem solving is just as much a scientific process of academia.

Comment: Are you worried about the future of EL&U or about your question?

Comment: Both (both both both)

Answer (score 8):

English is always evolving, but Stack Exchange in general and our site in particular are not a good place to ask people ["what colour should the bike shed be?"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding).

We're set up for questions that have definitive answers, supported by references where necessary (and it usually is necessary).

"I want to invent a word" is not what the main site is for.

There are plenty of [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) on the network where people would be happy to entertain such discussion. I'm sure [our main room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage-multi-layered-discourse-room) would be pleased to chat about it. There are plenty of other sites that are about creativity (not only in English) too, that would be happy to chat with you.

Comment: I also agree that "What colour should the bike shed be?" is irrelevant but getting back to the type of question which I am proposing to allow, I think that questions of academic nature which have to do with a more creative subject matter SHOULD be allowed.  In my case, I needed academic help to construct a word from Latin/Greek roots since the word did not exist.

Comment: "We're set up for questions that have definitive answers,"
That is simply not the case.  I can find many questions and answers here which multiple choices of preferred answer are acceptable. Since no two people communicate the same way, people with an advanced grasp of the nature of the English language can find multiple ways to communicate the same idea.
You are just plainly wrong.

Comment: ""I want to invent a word" is not what the main site is for."
Says you.  Word creation is a scientific part of English academia.  You are plainly wrong.
https://ecampusontario.pressbooks.pub/essentialsoflinguistics/chapter/6-6-creating-new-words/
I can find countless essays.  Bring your site up to academic standards.

Comment: @JoshuaRobison says not just me, but the community that uses the site. In your comment, when you say "scientific" what do you mean? You might find a more receptive crowd at [latin.se] or [linguistics.se]